# Are "close proposal" thresholds on Area 51 the same as on trilogy sites?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, area-51

Will it take 5 votes from the community (once people get the rep) to close a proposal on Area 51 like it does to close a question on an actual SE/trilogy site?

If so, is that really enough to shoot down an entire site proposal?  Or is the idea then to balance that with reopen votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it take five votes to close a site proposal. But it doesn't "shoot down" a proposal. Closed proposals can be re-opened in the same manner as a closed question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't see closing listed in the FAQ, was it removed?  (I [believe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52308/negative-voting-for-proposals/52309#52309) closing shouldn't be an option, though flagging a proposal offensive/spam should be allowed.)